# How to suppress download.file() "trying URL..." message in R?

Tags: r, download, message, gtfstools

I know the function has an `quiet` argument, but I'm trying to suppress the message when `quiet = FALSE`.

This may be weird, but I came across this issue when testing a package I'm writing. I'm using `testthat::expect_message()` when setting `quiet = FALSE`, but the function is not actually suppressing the message (it should, and in fact it usually does with "normal" messages).

I tried it with `suppressMessages()`, but it didn't work as expected:

```r
url <- "https://github.com/ipeaGIT/gtfstools/raw/master/inst/extdata/spo_gtfs.zip"
download.file(url, destfile = tempfile(), quiet = FALSE)
#> trying URL 'https://github.com/ipeaGIT/gtfstools/raw/master/inst/extdata/spo_gtfs.zip'
#> Content type 'application/zip' length 191108 bytes (186 KB)
#> downloaded 186 KB

suppressMessages(download.file(url, destfile = tempfile(), quiet = FALSE))
#> trying URL 'https://github.com/ipeaGIT/gtfstools/raw/master/inst/extdata/spo_gtfs.zip'
#> Content type 'application/zip' length 191108 bytes (186 KB)
#> downloaded 186 KB
```

Any ideas on how to suppress it, preferably without changing any `options`? It's not a lifethreatening situation, but it is making me curious.

Comment: Did I understand you correctly that you don't want to use the `quiet=TRUE` option because you "need" the messages for testing?

Comment: Perhaps a clearer phrasing of the question would be "How to make `testthat::expect_message()` suppress the generated message (as it normally does) for the `download.file()` command?"

Comment: The issue is that these messages are generated from `curl`, not from R. The `quiet = TRUE` option modifies the `curl` command to to ask `curl` to be quiet. So you'll need a way to intercept the command line output. `capture.output` might work, but I don't have time to experiment now...

Comment: @GregorThomas `utils::capture.output` does not work, probably for the reasons you stated. Mocking the function within the test could be an option though...

Comment: dario and GregorThomas, thanks for participating on this. Just to be clear, Gregor really framed the question better than I did, thanks for that! The reply from Joe below presents a good workaround for this.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`suppressMessages()` doesn't work because the progress text isn't an R `message()`, it's the stdout of the the system library that `download.file()` delegates the actual downloading to (e.g. `libcurl`, `wget` or `wininet`). `quiet = TRUE` bypasses this by setting the appropriate command line option of that tool.

You can divert stdout from the R console to a file with `sink()`. Since you don't need it, you can use `nullfile()` to open a file connection to the platform-dependent null device:

```r
url <- "https://github.com/ipeaGIT/gtfstools/raw/master/inst/extdata/spo_gtfs.zip"

nullcon <- file(nullfile(), open = "wb")
sink(nullcon, type = "message")
download.file(url, destfile = tempfile(), quiet = FALSE)
sink(type = "message")
close(nullcon)
```

Note that the second-to-last line is very important – it ends the diversion. Without it, all further messages in the R session will be sent to `/dev/null`.

Also bear in mind the following warnings from `?sink`:

> Do not use a connection that is open for sink for any other purpose. The software will stop you closing one such inadvertently.
>
> Do not sink the messages stream unless you understand the source code implementing it and hence the pitfalls.

Personally I'd say this method is too risky to use in a package, especially when the `quiet = TRUE` option is available.

Comment: Great answer, thanks! Yup, I don't intend on using it in the package. I just wanted to get rid of this message that was bugging me a bit when running the tests, but upon this warning from `?sink` I'll leave it like it is. Cheers!